# Best ethereum testnet to deploy smart contracts for IoTs

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, testnets, raspberry-pi, iot

I want to run a local private Ethereum blockchain on Pis for:

- To deploy smart contracts
- To be able to read and control IoT

Need advice in:

- Which testnet is most suitable for this
- Will it work on HDD or do I need SSD
- How much space would I need to be able to run the test net
- Or is it advised to directly  go for mainnet

Currently using [this guide](http://core-geth.org/setup-on-raspberry-pi) for the setup

Comment: I would go with Göerli, it is the fastest one among Ethereum testnets in my experience. You will definitely need an SSD at least, HDD will be very slow and won't be able to sync. You can check out the [geth documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#a-full-node-on-the-g%C3%B6rli-test-network) for Goerli installation guide.